# Delegating of functionality to child classes in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, interface

I have some object model(e.g. commands)  which can be marshaled to some textual representation. I have two options:

1. Assume that every subclass of Command will correctly override "toString"
2. Create interface with "marshal" and "unmarshal" methods that every child will be ought to implement.

Which option is better for such delegation? I mean, toString has really close meaning, but it doesn't give me a guarantee that child class just doesn't use standard implementation of toString.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I think the approach with explicit methods is far superior.** You've pretty much nailed the reasons:

> Assume that every subclass of Command will correctly override "toString"

Every single maintenance programmer to touch the code will need to be aware of this assumption. If they suddenly decide that it would be nice that some class's `toString()` included an additional piece of information (say for debugging), the code will unexpectedly break.

> Create interface with "marshal" and "unmarshal" methods that every child will be ought to implement.

This makes the API explicit, hard to fail to implement, and much harder to accidentally break or misuse.

It also means that certain errors can be caught at compile time. You can have a method that takes `IMarshallable`, and the compiler won't let you pass anything that doesn't implement the interface. With the first approach, every object has a `toString()` method, and there's no way for the compiler to know whether a particular object's `toString()` implements your marshalling protocol. This means that it can't diagnose this type of error at compile time.

Comment: "*Impossible* to fail to implement" is overstating just a tiny bit.  A subclass that extends an implementer of the Command interface, might not override the already-existing `marshal` and `unmarshal`.  At which point you either end up de/serializing an instance of the base class or getting a half-baked instance of the subclass (depending on how the serialization is done).

Comment: @cHao: Fair enough. I was thinking of a setup where only the final classes implement the marshalling. I'll edit the wording.

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely use interfaces and/or abstract classes (methods). Relying on *toString* is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't normally expect `toString()` to implement functionality used in anything other than diagnostics or similar.

I'd much rather implement a marshall/unmarshall mechanism. Note that this could potentially be very powerful. e.g. you provide the source/destination as arguments to the `marshall()`/`unmarshall()` mechanism and the object could mediate with the source/destination to marshall itself in one or more modes (essentially a *visitor* pattern)

Answer (score 0):

> I mean, toString has really close meaning

The purpose of `toString` is to provide a textual representation for an object, which is meant to be read for people, and mainly meant to be used for debugging. This is what the API documentation of `java.lang.Object.toString()` says:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read.

It is specifically not meant to return a string in some format that is machine readable, and that you can convert back (unmarshal) into an object again.

So, `toString()` is not meant to what you seem to want to use it for: convert an object to a string (marshal) that can later be converted back to an object (unmarshal).

It's far better to create an interface that declares `marshal` and `unmarshal` methods, and make classes that need this functionality implement this interface. By making a class implement the interface, it is also immediately clear that the class supports this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

U can use library class `org.apache.commons.lang3.builder.ToStringBuilder`. It provides deep `toString` with all attributes value. There are a few setups.